# Auto Adding Devices to BFGMiner

Tags: miner-configuration, asic, bfgminer

Every time I launch BFG Miner I have to add the devices by entering the com port it is on. Is there anyway to do this automatically?

Here is my start script:

```
bfgminer -o stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 -u Bgordy2014.RaspberryPi -p PW -G
```

I was thinking along the lines of -D erupter:\.\COM3

D equaling devices

Answer (score 3):

`-S all` will attempt autodetection.